# How to make headers with tables and pictures?

Tags: tables, graphics, header-footer, tabularx

First of all I wanted to thank the community for all the help I've found on this website.
I'm relatively new to TeX and I'm trying to make headers composed with tables and pictures like the two ones below :
[image: First header I'm trying to make]

[image: Second header I'm trying to make]

So I've tried to find similar topics on this forum and by merging them together Ive made the following code :

```
    \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makecell,multirow,tabularx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage[top=5cm,headheight=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}%
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhead[CE,CO,LE,LO,RE,RO]{} 
\fancyhead[C]{%
    \centering
    \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.3}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|cX|p{10cm}|p{2cm}|}
    \hline
\multirow{3}{*}{\includegraphics[width=1.5cm]{Figures/logo.png}}
    &      &   \textbf{Title of the document}     &   page \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}
    &                           &           &                   \\
    &                           &           &        \\
    \hline
    & File name
                                &    Revision &   Activity domain :          \\
    \hline
    \end{tabularx}%
            }



\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-20]

\end{document}
```

This code generates a header that is much simplier that the one I want, and with a lot of problems : the right column disapears, some text is overlapping the columns, ...

How do you think I could improve my code to make this work?

Thanks a lot for your help,

Gary

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: I suppose that by ‘header’, you mean a ‘heading’ (not repeated on each page)?

Comment: As far I see you need a `twoside` option in first line and some fix on the table, try some like `\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|c|>{\centering}X|p{2cm}|}\hline
    \multirow{3}{*}{\includegraphics[width=1.5cm]{example-image}}  &   \multirow{3}{*}{\textbf{Title of the document}}  &   page \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage} \\\cline{3-3}
 & & bah \\ \cline{3-3}
&  & foo \\\hline\end{tabularx}`

Comment: The first one must be on the front page but the second one must repeat on each page. 
I'll try your propositio and come back with a feedback.
Thank you,

Answer (score 2):

I think this code is close to what you want.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{kantlipsum} % dummy text
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{bigstrut,array}
\usepackage{lastpage}

\usepackage[top=5cm, bottom=3cm, left=2.5cm, right=2cm, headheight=3.5cm]{geometry}

%\usepackage{showframe}  %added for testing
%\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}   %added for testing


\fancypagestyle{firststyle}{%
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
    \fancyhead[L]{
        \textsf{\bfseries%
        \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
            \cline{1-6}
            \multirow{4}[8]{*}{\includegraphics[height=0.10\textwidth,width=0.10\textwidth]{example-image-a}} & \multicolumn{3}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{0.60\textwidth}|}{\multirow{4}[8]{*}{\large Title}} & \multicolumn{2}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{0.20\textwidth}|}{\footnotesize File name: } \bigstrut\\
            \cline{5-6}  
            & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\footnotesize Revision: XXX} & \multicolumn{1}{p{40pt}|}{\footnotesize{page \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}} \bigstrut\\
            \cline{5-6}  
            & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{\footnotesize Efective date:} \bigstrut\\
            \cline{5-6} 
            & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{\footnotesize Activity domain: } \bigstrut\\
            \cline{1-6}
            \multicolumn{6}{|c|}{} \bigstrut\\
            \cline{1-6}
        \end{tabular*}%
    }}}

\pagestyle{fancy}{%
    \fancyhead[L,R]{}
    \fancyhead[L]{%
\textsf{\bfseries%
    \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
        \cline{1-6}
        \multirow{4}[8]{*}{\includegraphics[height=0.10\textwidth,width=0.10\textwidth]{example-image-a}} & \multicolumn{4}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{0.7\textwidth}|}{\multirow{4}[7]{*}{\large Title}} & \multicolumn{1}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{0.1\textwidth}|}{\multirow{4}[6]{*}{\footnotesize{page \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}} }\bigstrut[t]\\
        \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{}         &  \\
        \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{}         &  \\
        \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{}         &  \\
        \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{}         &  \bigstrut[b]\\
        \cline{1-6}
        \multicolumn{2}{|>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{0.3\textwidth}|}{File name: } & \multicolumn{2}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{0.3\textwidth}|}{Revision:} & \multicolumn{2}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{0.3\textwidth}|}{Activity domain: } \bigstrut[t]\\
        \cline{1-6}
    \end{tabular*}%
}}}
    
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\begin{document}
        
\thispagestyle{firststyle}

\kant[1-34]
    
\end{document}
```

[image: nnn]

The `\fancypagestyle{firststyle}` is applied only to the fist page, then the fancy style is used for the following pages.

The headers are similar, tables using `tabular*` to set the width, and some `multirow` & `multicolumn` to make the desired design. The packages `multirow`, `array` and `bigstrut` are needed to compile.

If you want to visualize the layout, uncomment the two lines marked as  `added for testing`.
It is useful when dealing with  `geometry`.

*Task left for the reader*: For an operative and reusable solution you could define commands like

```
\newcommand{\wtitle}{This is the title of the work}
\newcommand{\wrevision}{Rev. 4a}
\newcommand{\wfilename}{firstproposal.tex}
```

and so on. Then insert these commands in the appropriator places of the template of the two tables.