# Same feature on every page

Tags: header-footer, positioning, minipage, styles

I would like to have the same feature on every page. For instance, on one page, I created two minipages, which are now on top of the page. I would like to have this similarly on every page (I guess not in the header, but in the main part of the page).

Is there a way to "separate" some part of the page somehow and tell LaTex to put there the same feature again, on every page, at the same position? In my case, it's the top of the page, but it could be somewhere else.

Thanks in advance

Comment: See this answer that uses the `fancyhdr` package. It may help to start. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/574265/how-to-make-headers-with-tables-and-pictures/574339#574339

Comment: See the flowfram package to reallocate the text area over some or all pages.