# Header as multi column table with image

Tags: tables, graphics, header-footer

Currently I'm working on converting a documentation Word template to Latex. All pages(except cover) must have a header just like the picture below:

[image: Header]

All pages must have a border, so this is also conflicting to positionate the header at the top. I tried to use a tabular but I'm getting errors with the '\includegraphics' for logo. Is this stuff possible with LaTeX?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. As reference, start here, perhaps: [Tables as Header and footer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/113240/5764)

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/574339/161015